# Object fails to instantiate on Win7 x64

Tags: c#, database, x86, 64-bit, sqlconnection

I've searched quite a bit and turned up nothing helpful so here I am.

I have written an app in C# (Any CPU setting) that has been running on Windows 7 and XP x86 for some time now without error.

Recently my office has upgraded my workstation to Windows 7 x64 (from x86).

When I run my application in Visual Studio 2010 I receive no errors at run or compile time.  It works as designed.

My VS2010 version is 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel from our MSDN subscription, Framework is 4.0.30319 RTMRel

When I run my compiled application directly I receive an error when with the SqlConnection object.  It does not matter if i choose ANY CPU or x86 the same errors occur.

In my class file this is the routine:

```
        public static SqlConnection getDBConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KpH2Oprod"].ConnectionString);
            sqlConn.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConn == null)
            {
                sqlConn.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return sqlConn;
    }
```

Some manual tracing I found the error to be thrown not after `SqlConnection sqlConn = null;` when it's first instantiated but when I actually set it on the line:

```
sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KpH2Oprod"].ConnectionString);
```

I have changed this line to:

```
 sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
 sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KpH2Oprod"].ConnectionString;
```

to see if it was the SqlConnection or to Configuration manager and indeed it throws on the `sqlConn = new SqlConnection();` line.  In fact this was the way I started and changed it to the previous, no matter, both throw error on using the new directive.

The actual error message I get back is (some of which is my own message):

I believe that this might be related to how the SQL object are registered but the message is truncate in the center of the first few lines (not my doing) that point to the parameter g being null.  Again this works in the debugger flawlessly.

```
RunTimeError : 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
at kpH2O.frmMain..ctor() (mscorlib)

ACTION : 
UPDATEINCIDENT ()

PROGRESS : 
WORKING ()

RunTimeError : 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at kpH2O.db.getDBConnection()
at kpH2O.db.getIncidentIDFromNumber(String incidentNumber)
at kpH2O.frmMain.updateHeatIncident() (kpH2O)

ERROR : 
Process UPDATEINCIDENT: FAILED (doStartUp)
```

This is an out of the box VS2010 install without any addons.  Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to capture just the raw exception / stack trace?

Comment: Also - there is no benefit to having a catch clause that has nothing but a throw statement in it.

Comment: Here is the same situation as you have  http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2004/08/13/214135.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE: The connection string doesn't matter because he gets the exception before even setting the connection string property.

Answer (score 0):

To validate functionality, I would test with a snippet like this. Your current code has a flaw in the disposition logic which is just complicating things.

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KpH2Oprod"].ConnectionString;

using( SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) )
{
    sc.Open();
    // perform simple data access
}
```

Comment: The point of the function is to return a SqlConnection object. Returning a disposed object would be useless!

Comment: Gabe I think that you are jumping the gun. what they are saying is that the way his code is structured ..he could never return a valid SQLConnection object based on the way his code was originally written.. @Tim has made probably the best recommedation by far in my opinion aslo makes me wonder what his using section looks like in the header does he use using System.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: @Gabe - Exactly, I was pointing out that the OPs current code will either throw a `NullReferenceException` in the finally block or (if updated to fix the null check) will dispose the connection before the caller can use it.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: The OP's code *always* returns a valid object *except* on Win 7 x64 when not under a debugger (where the `SqlConnection` constructor throws an exception). The way to fix the exception handling is to remove it (as currently it does nothing). The "fix" proposed would make his code *never* work.

Answer (score 0):

how is the Connection string defined in your .config file for starters..?
would need to see that much

also I would look at defining your sqlConn like this

```
sqlConn = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"]; //assuming this is what you named your connection string..
```

Second I would make use of Try catch {} as well as putting the using (){} within that try

if you do not want to dispose of that sqlConn.. then make it a static property

public static SQLConnection sqlConn = null;

then if you need to use it .. use the new construct within the using() {} as described above.. 
look at this link as well if you want to Enumerate connection string variables using your original construct [ConfigurationSetting and manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for the delay on getting back on this.  This has become a non-issue.  My computer crashed...twice... and the techs reinstalled it with Windows 7 32 bit and the application works fine again.

Comment: sounds good but I wonder if you had an update issue with win7 64bit I have only had one issue ..Knock on wood with VS2010 / 2008 on my wind 7 64 bit but installed the updates for vs and no more issues.. sorry to hear that your pc kept crashing..